# Inserting date 1 year from now into mysql Date column

Tags: java, mysql

I have a column in mysql table of type `Date` called `expiryDate`.

I want to get the date one year from now, and insert this into the `expiryDate` column.

I get the date 1 year from now:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

// expires 1 year fron now
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate yearLater = localDate.plusYears ( 1 );
```

I get the error when I try to insert:

```
Incorrect date value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x17org.joda.time.LocalDate\xFF\xFF\xF8\x04\xD3\xE4\xEB\xB5\x02\x00\x02J\x00\x0CiLocalMillisL\x00\x0BiChro' for column 'expiryDate'

arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{expiryDate:2019-02-01,balance:50,orderId:761...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should covert your joda date to a format understood by MySQL driver. But you didn't mention what you are doing before the error occurs (how you access the DB).

Comment: Please show java code with your insert statement. It seems as it tries to insert the Object.toString() result into the database instead of a formatted date string.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you could use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) with `INTERVAL 1 YEAR`

```
SELECT NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

**[>>Demo<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71e98c/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

It will have no issue with MySQL driver.